# Slide Right to Left using ObjectAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I can do the slide left to right thanks to the sample code given in this YouTube link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UbJhmkeSig

However I can't do the right to left animation. What I've tried is putting a '-' (negative) sign in the code below but it wont work and it gives me the error:

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to
>   'android.util.Property

```
ObjectAnimator translateAnimation =
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, -View.TRANSLATION_X, 800);
        translateAnimation.start();
        translateAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
        translateAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
```

Any way to do this inside an Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work on the value, while the property name should remain the same:

```
ObjectAnimator translateAnimation =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_X, -view.getWidth());
    translateAnimation.start();
    translateAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
    translateAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
```

Comment: I tried doing it, it works however why is it goes too much to the left and disappears. Shouldn't it just go back to the normal position? Oh by the way I tried doing it without the "setRepeatCount" and "setRepeatMode" methods. I tried doing it with different buttons

Comment: 800 should be a parameter computed from the width of the view.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean.